# Read data in excel file and write as WAV file. Modify program to read name of the output WAV file from CCS console

Tags: c++, c, excel, csv, wav

// My code is not outputting what I want, can some please drop some knowledge. I am having trouble reading the input file correctly. I am also having trouble using fscanf to read the name of the output file.

```
fp2 = fopen("..\\OUT.csv", "rb");   // Open input file
fp3 = fopen("..\\C55DSPUSBStickAudioTest.wav", "wb");   // Open output file


fseek(fp3, 44, 0);                          // Advance output file point 44 bytes
i=0;
p=0;

while (fread(ch, sizeof(Uint16), SIZE, fp2) == SIZE) // Read in SIZE of input data bytes
{
    for (k=0;k<SIZE;k++)
    {
        O1[2*k]=(Uint8)(O & 0xFF);
        O1[2*k+1]=(Uint8)(O>>8)&0xFF;
    }
    fwrite(O1,sizeof(Uint8),SIZE,fp3);
    p += SIZE;
    printf("%ld bytes processed\n",p);
}
fscanf(fp3,"%u",&O);
```

Comment: Hi, please be more specific to understand the issue, can you give some examples having issues in reading input?

Comment: The program should convert the excel file from 16bit to 8 bit then write to the wav file. And after read the name of the wav file. My code runs with no errors but I am doing it wrong.